# Python: "too many values to unpack" when assigning result of str.split()

Tags: python-2.7, split, iterable-unpacking

I have a file like this:

```
a       hello
b       goodbye
c       submarine
```

I want to save it to a dictionary like this:

```
file = {'a': 'hello', 'b': 'goodbye', 'c': 'submarine'}
```

I tried this:

```
file={}
with open("the actual file") as f:
    for line in f:
        key , value = line.split()
        file[key] = val
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: There is no other text in any of the lines?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have lines with more than two whitespace-separated words, like e.g.

```
a       hello
b       goodbye
c       submarine
d       some words
```

`line.split()` would split the last line above into a list of 3 items, `["d", "some", "words"]`.

As you only can (and want to) handle two items, the key (first word) and the value (everything else), we have to pass another argument to the `split()` function which specifies how often the string should be split at most. We want two items, so it may only get split once here. We have to add `None` as first argument because we must also specify a delimiter then, and `None` is the default and represents all types of whitespace.

In short, change your code line to this:

```
        key, value = line.split(None, 1)
```

Comment: If this answer solves your question, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the grey round check symbol on its left. In case you have further questions or something still does not work as intended, let me know in a comment below.

Comment: `line.split(2)` yields a TypError, as it's treating the `2` as the delimiter and it's not a `str`. Also, the number specifies how many splits (not how many elements it returns). You actually want `line.split(None, 1)`

Comment: @SiHa Oops, you're absolutely right. Editing that. Thanks!